# Can't Get Real-time Progress Updates for Video Upload with Moya in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, moya

I'm using the Moya library to upload videos in my iOS app and am trying to get real-time progress updates. However, I only receive a progress update when the upload completes, at which point the progress value jumps to 1.0, without any intermediate values. Here is the code snippet I'm working with:

```
    func createMoyaProvider<Target: TargetType>(targetType: Target.Type) -> MoyaProvider<Target> {
    // let provider = MoyaProvider<Target>(plugins: [NetworkLoggerPlugin(configuration: .init())])
    let provider = MoyaProvider<Target>()
    provider.session.sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120
    return provider
}

    let provider = createMoyaProvider(targetType: VideoTarget.self)
var cancellable: Cancellable?

func uploadVideo(listingId: String, asset: PHAsset, fileName: String, progress: @escaping (Double) -> Void, completion: @escaping (Result<Response, MoyaError>) -> Void) {
    PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: nil) { (avAsset, _, _) in
        guard let urlAsset = avAsset as? AVURLAsset else {
            completion(.failure(MoyaError.underlying(NSError(domain: "VideoServiceError", code: -1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Unable to resolve video."]), nil)))
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let videoData = try Data(contentsOf: urlAsset.url)
            self.cancellable = self.provider.request(.uploadVideo(listingId: listingId, videoData: videoData, fileName: fileName), callbackQueue: .main, progress: { (progressResponse) in
                print(progressResponse.progress)
                progress(progressResponse.progress)
            }) { result in
                completion(result)
            }
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(MoyaError.underlying(error, nil)))
        }
    }
}
extension VideoTarget: MTargetType {
var isAuthorization: Bool {
    switch self {
    default:
        return true
    }
}


var path: String {
    switch self {
    case .uploadVideo(let listingId, _, _):
        return "\(listingId)/video"
    }
}

var method: Moya.Method {
    switch self {
    case .uploadVideo:
        return .post
    default:
        return .get
    }
}

var task: Task {
    switch self {
    case .uploadVideo(_, let videoData, let fileName):
        let videoMultipart = MultipartFormData(provider: .data(videoData), name: "file", fileName: "\(fileName).mp4", mimeType: "video/mp4")
        return .uploadMultipart([videoMultipart])
    default:
        return .requestPlain
    }
}
```

}

Has anyone faced a similar issue or have suggestions on how to receive continuous progress updates during the upload process?

Comment: Why is this tagged with Alamofire since you seem to use Moya only? Also, do you use another lib to "track" HTTP requests? I know it can causes issue with Progresses